# Pivoter tabla in SP Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un caso donde tengo que pivotear una tabla temp que utilizo en SP, esta tabla debe tener un formato por Numero de Mes ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi sp ejecuta lo siguiente:, pero para lograr lo anterior es necesario un pivot, pero sinceramente he intentado hacerlo pero no he conseguido exito

```
SELECT IdFactura,SUM(total) as Total,datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, Fecha)/7 * 7)/7 + 1 as NumerWeek, Nombre from #Docs as pvt
GROUP BY IdFactura,Fecha,Nombre

PIVOT (SUM(pvt.total) FOR pvt.NumerWeek IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) AS Child
ORDER BY IdFactura

DROP TABLE #Docs

END
```

espero pueda ayudarme para poder realizar esta caso.

Answer (score 1):

Rafiña este codigo te puedde ayudar

```
select 
    nombre,
    [1] AS 'Semana_1',
    [2] AS 'Semana_2',
    [3] AS 'Semana_3',
    [4] AS 'Semana_4',
    [5] AS 'Semana_5'
from(
    select nombre,NumerWeek,total
    from temp
) as source
pivot
(
    sum(total)
    for NumerWeek in (  
                        [1],
                        [2],
                        [3],
                        [4],
                        [5]
                    )
) as pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

Proba con una subconsulta y esta hacerla PIVOT

```
Select IdFactura, Total,NumerWeek,Nombre  from (
SELECT IdFactura,SUM(total) as Total,datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, Fecha)/7 * 7)/7 + 1 as NumerWeek, Nombre from #Docs as pvt
GROUP BY IdFactura,Fecha,Nombre ) Tpivot PIVOT (SUM(pvt.total) FOR pvt.NumerWeek IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])) AS Child
ORDER BY IdFactura
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que hacer primero es establecer las columnas dinámicamente, en tu caso sería el número de semanas:

```
declare @columnas varchar(max)

select @columnas =  coalesce(@columnas + '[' + cast(NumeroSemana as varchar(12)) + '],', '')
FROM (select distinct NumeroSemana from TablaParaPivot) as DTM
set @columnas = left(@columnas,LEN(@columnas)-1)
```

Una vez que tienes el número de columnas, pivotas la tabla:

```
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(max)

set @SQLString = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT NumeroSemana, Total, Nombre as NombreCliente  FROM TablaParaPivot) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(sum (Total) FOR NumeroSemana IN (' + @columnas + ') ) AS PivotTable'
```

Finalmente ejecutas la consulta:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor para este caso es implementar un pivote dinámico de esta manera:

```
declare @attr varchar(max)declare @sql varchar(max)set @attr=''
set @sql='
 select 
        Nombre as NombreCliente,
        #attr#
 from 
     ( 
      SELECT
              idfactura, Total, NumerWeek, Nombre
        FROM docs
      ) as source pivot (
            max(Total)
      for NumerWeek in (
                     #attr#
                    )

     ) as pvt
     ' 
select @attr=@attr+'['+cast(v.NumerWeek as varchar)+'],'from (    
    select distinct NumerWeek FROM docs
) as v

set @attr=SUBSTRING(@attr,0,len(@attr))
set @sql=REPLACE(@sql,'#attr#',@attr)
print @sql
exec(@sql)
```

En esta consulta primero se define la estructura del pivote y posteriormente se insertan dinamicamente las columnas correspondientes a cada semana con sus valores de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]