# UNPIVOT usando variables en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql

Estoy haciendo un UNPIVOT para poder obtener un Total por MES

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tabla
UNPIVOT
(
TOTAL FOR MES IN ([ENE-20])
) AS UPIVOT
```

El detalle es que cuando tengan que ver información de otros año me mostrara que la columna de mes no existe por que ahora la columna se llamara [ENE-21], [ENE-22] etc.

Por lo cual estoy utilizando esta función para obtener el nombre de la columna

```
DECLARE @ENE NVARCHAR(20)

SET @ENE = (SELECT COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('dbo.Tabla'), 1) AS FirstColumnName)
```

No se como utilizar la variable en el UNPIVOT, tengo la siguiente consulta.

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla
UNPIVOT
(
TOTAL FOR MES IN ([@ENE])
) AS UPIVOT
```

Comment: Lo que pides es hacer un unpivot dinámico, lo cual es posible pero puede indicar que estás tomando información del lugar incorrecto. Cuando los nombres de las columnas cambian, por lo general es porque se creo una tabla desde un query, es mejor obtener la información de la misma fuente de ese query.

Comment: Respuesta rápida: no puedes. Deberías crear la consulta de forma dinámica y luego ejecutarla. Hay algunas respuestas en el sitio que apuntan a este problema, por ejemplo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/296566/como-puedo-pasarle-una-consulta-a-un-pivot/296572#296572 o https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7916/pivoter-tabla-in-sp-sql-server/8976#8976